# Is the $\omega$-product of the set of irrationals compact?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, compactness

We know that any product of compact spaces is compact. But, I wonder that the countable product of $\mathbb{P}$ can be compact since $\mathbb{P}$ is not compact?

Comment: You have received some good answers, explaining that a product of nonempty topological spaces can't be compact unless all the factors are compact. In the special case you asked about, where $P$ is the space of irrational numbers, it is a theorem that $P^\omega$ is homeomorphic to $P$; in fact $P$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb N^\omega$, so $p^\omega$ is homeomorphic to $(\mathbb N^\omega)^\omega$, which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb N^\omega$, which is homeomorphic to $P$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of the $X_i$'s is not compact, say $X_{i_0}$, then $X=\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ is also non-compact, as you can construct an open cover of $X$ without finite subcover.

Take for example a cover where the open sets are products of all the $X_i$'s except of $X_{i_0}$, and multiply by open subsets $U_j$, $j\in J$, of $X_{i_0}$, which constitute an open cover of $X_{i_0}$ without an open subcover. Then 
$$
U_j\times \prod_{i\in I\smallsetminus\{i_0\}}X_i, \quad j\in J,
$$
is a cover of $X$ without a finite subcover.

Comment: To be on the safe side, you might add the assumption that the spaces $X_i$ are nonempty.

Answer (score 1):

if $A$ is note compact of a  topologic space  $X$ since the projection $p: X^2 \to X$  is continous by definition of product topology ands $p(A^2)=A$ if $A^2$  is compact then $p(A^2)=A$ is compact.

Answer (score 0):

The cartesian product $X \times Y$ of a non-compact space $X$ and any nonempty topological space $Y$ is never compact.  Namely, if $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is an open cover of $X$ with no finite subcover, $\{U_\alpha \times Y\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is
an open cover of $X \times Y$ with no finite subcover.

Comment: OK.  I edited it.